# How to use signature algorithm SHA-1 in php function openssl_pkcs7_sign

Tags: php, openssl

Used this code to sign file, but with different OpenSSL versions, the different result, or SHA-1 or SHA-256 turns out. It is necessary to set SHA-1.

```php
openssl_pkcs7_sign($inFilename, $outFilename, "file://".$publicCertFile, "file://privateCertFile", array(), PKCS7_DETACHED | PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_NOATTR);
```

Result:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/x-pkcs7-signature"; micalg="sha-256"; boundary="----592DF2A997B872976D85E98B5BC89799"
...
...
```

The algorithm of sha-256 was used.

Working OpenSSL command:

```sh
openssl smime -sign -md sha1 -in "INFILE.TXT" -inkey private.pem -signer public.pem -binary -outform DER -noattr > FILE.RSA
```

In command line it is possible to set algorithm and how to make it in PHP?

Comment: Any answers ? I met this,too

Comment: Anyone found the solution ??